# In Drools, how do I check if a list does NOT contain an object with a specific value?

Tags: java, drools

I am making a rule that looks at a list of given objects and checks if one of the string fields does not contain a certain value.  If any object in the list contain said value then I want the rule to fail.

```
    when
        $vr: RequestDTO($activeObjects: activeObjects);
        eval(!$activeObjects contains ObjectDTO(this.name == "TEST NAME")); 
    then
        displayModalAction.setMessage("Message to Show");
    end
```

Is there a way to do this sort of action in the *when* statement of the rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you are looking for RequestDTOs that don't have an ObjectDTO with a name of "TEST NAME".  If that's correct, then try this:

```
when
    RequestDTO($activeObjects: activeObjects)
    not exists(ObjectDTO(name == "TEST NAME") from $activeObjects)
then
    ...
```

Comment: I could not use not with exists.  It through an error saying it expected a conditional after not.

Comment: I didn't need to use "not exists", just "not" by itself. This got me on the right track.